# Multiple monitors with KVM

Tags: multiple-monitors, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

This is my first try to use KVM (have been using VirtualBox for years) and everything was pretty easy to do except getting the VM to display on more than one monitor (I have 2). Both my host and guest are Ubuntu GNOME 16.04.1.

Per various doc, posts etc I have

```
> Set Display to Type:Spice server

> Set Video to Model: QXL (under which it says "Heads: 1"
```

I tried adding a second QXL device but when I booted the VM I only got a terminal, no desktop GUI.

An additional note: On the guest, in Display Settings there is only one display.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `virt-manager` you can navigate to the video device in the VM details and switch to the XML tab to directly edit the libvirt domain xml. You should see a `heads='1'` attribute, you can set this up to *4* I believe.

See the documentation on video devices [on the libvirt website](https://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#video-devices) for additional settings. Specifically if you're using QXL and using resolutions you may run out of video memory and will need to increase the `vram` value.

You can then select the number of displays being shown in `virt-viewer` by going to `View -> Displays -> *check displays to show*`

Answer (score 1):

[This advice](https://access.redhat.com/discussions/1363063) did the trick for me.

Add 2nd display adapter in KVM manager and use `remote-viewer spice://localhost:5900`.

Answer (score 0):

In Proxmox KVM, I am doing everything properly, have spice-vdagent installed in VM Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop (gnome), but still the system won't see in display settings any extra monitor, and clicking display 2 in remote-viewer doesn't do anything.

I've seen that people have had this problem with different Ubuntu versions (ranging probably to even 16.04 LTS already then), and I have encountered that this might be problem with HWE kernel, so perhaps reinstalling to GA kernel can fix the problem:

https://stafwag.github.io/blog/blog/2018/04/22/high-screen-resolution-on-a-kvm-virtual-machine-with-qxl/

https://askubuntu.com/a/1011440/702332

I haven't tried that but I will give it a shot some day in the future.

I also reported the case here and in other places:

https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/spice-dual-monitor-from-windows-7-guest.52296/