# Enabling multiple screens on KVM/spice Ubuntu guest

Tags: multiple-monitors, kvm-virtualization, guest-os, spice

I have installed Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 with KVM in a bare metal server.  Then, using virt-manager, I have created a brand new Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 guest with a single QXL Video device and a Spice server.  I'm accessing this VM using virt-viewer (Remote Viewer) on a Windows desktop machine.  My understanding is that Spice should provide as many as four virtual displays to enable a multiple monitor environment on the client side.  However, when I select view->displays in the virt-viewer, displays 2-4 are grayed out and not selectable.  The command 'xrandr' performed on the guest indicates that Virtual-0 is connected/primary and Virtual-1 through -3 are disconnected.  I can add modes to Virtual-1 using

```
xrander --addmode Virtual-1 1024x768
```

but when I try to connect it using the following command

```
xrander --output Virtual-1 -d 1 --mode 1024x768
```

I get 'Can't open display 1'.  Is the problem that I need to activate more X-displays?  If so, how do I do that?

The server I'm using is a Dell R210 II with only the default Intel graphics and only one physical monitor connected, but my understanding is that these are virtual graphics devices, not pass-thrus, so the hardware shouldn't matter.  Is that wrong?  Any helps is appreciated!

Comment: Solved the initial problem (see answer below regarding spice-vdagent install).  Now I have a new problem.  After the host and the guest restarted, I get the following behavior.  I can initially connect to the guest using virt-viewer and it opens a single screen.  When I try to select the additional screen, it lets me, but the first screen turns black and the second screen says "Waiting for display 2".  After that, I can no longer access any screens for the guest, even from the host, so I think I killed all the displays.  I can still ssh.  restarting `spice-vdagent` doesn't help.

Comment: I ended up recreating the VM and running `spice-vdagent` within the guest and everything seems to be working fine now.  I must have messed something up with the old VM, so I'd consider the below answer suitable.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that I did not know I needed to install `spice-vdagent` within the guest machine.  Doing that enabled me to select the additional displays.  That initially fixed the problem.  Now I have a new problem, so I was leery about posting this as a solution until I confirm they are unrelated.  See comments above.

Answer (score 0):

In Proxmox KVM, I am doing everything properly, have spice-vdagent installed in VM Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop (gnome), but still the system won't see in display settings any extra monitor, and clicking display 2 in remote-viewer doesn't do anything.

I've seen that people have had this problem with different Ubuntu versions (ranging probably to even 16.04 LTS already then), and I have encountered that this might be problem with HWE kernel, so perhaps reinstalling to GA kernel can fix the problem:

https://stafwag.github.io/blog/blog...resolution-on-a-kvm-virtual-machine-with-qxl/

https://askubuntu.com/a/1011440/702332

I haven't tried that but I will give it a shot some day in the future.

I also reported the case here and in other places:

https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/spice-dual-monitor-from-windows-7-guest.52296/

Answer (score 0):

@Tomeg, I had the same problem as yourself selecting the second display, using Proxmox Virtual Environment 6.4-8, Ubuntu Guest with display configured as SPICE Dual Monitor (qxl) and using virt-viewer (latest as of posting).

**Note:** It was originally working, then stopped working after disabling it and powering the guest off.

**This worked for me:**

1. Ran `xrandr` from the shell on the Ubuntu 20.4 guest, this showed me that the Virtual-2 to Virtual-4 displays were disconnected.
2. Then ran the following to enable the Virtual-2 display and the second display appeared (automatically enabled within virt-viewer):

```
xrandr --addmode Virtual-2 1920x1080
xrandr --output Virtual-2 --mode 1920x1080 --right-of Virtual-1
```

**Additional Note:** If I now disable the second display from within virt-viewer and power the guest off, I have to follow the same process to get it working again.

Hope this helps..